zsh: argument list too long - How to increase the limit?
As mentioned here the argument size of a command is quite limited. That's when you get zsh: argument list too long.
On my machine it seems to be
$ sysctl kern.argmax                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
kern.argmax: 1048576

So, already at 50k files with 25 character names, we have 1250000 and that's too much. Which seems a bit silly on a machine with 64 GB of RAM.
sysctl -a -W doesn't list argmax suggesting that it cannot be changed at runtime.
Can this limit be increased somehow instead of working around the issue with xargs/zargs/zcp/…?

man sysctl lists kern.argmax as “not changeable.”

What is causing your argument list to grow? Do you need to exec or can you use built in? The xargs idiom is very well regarded (tested / known / performant) and specifically designed for handling data larger than $ARG_MAX such as common very long path-length with hundreds or thousands of files being sent through the same pipeline.

Sarien: What is the command you are trying to execute? It would seem to me you could use the find command with the -exec option to run your command on each argument. See the answer posted by nohillside.

I could, it just requires that I use more brain cells than I would have to with simple glob matching.

Instead of increasing the limit and stumbling over a new limit later, how about fixing your program, so that it is not dependent on that limit anymore?

@user1934428: The OP has already posted a link to a question that has such answers. I posted a comment about using find and the OP responded by rejecting such answers. Otherwise, I would have already closed the question as a duplicate. (I and my others have enough reputation to do so.)

@DavidAnderson : I agree with you (sadly, my reputation is not sufficient to vote for closing). However, the OP did not write in which situation he gets the error message, so we can't be sure that the answer he linked to, will help it. I would vote to close the question on the grounds that it lacks details.

I think the question has the necessary details. I am looking for a solution which makes the same simple code rm foo* work no matter how many files there are in the directory. On modern computers a limit of a couple ten thousand files is just not reasonable. Using for file in foo* or xargs solutions work but imho those are workarounds not fixes.

I agree about "just not reasonable". However, in your case the problem here isn’t  the computer or OS.  You are asking the shell to expand foo*, which evidently results in many filenames being generated. Architecturally, historically yours is the wrong approach and designed to fail. You need to get a command to search for names matching "foo*", instead of relying on the shell to do the search. This happens if you enter find . -name "foo*" -maxdepth 1 -exec rm {} \; instead. Here, "foo*" is in double quotes and therefore is not expanded by the shell to a long list of filenames.

Under Windows, the command would be del foo*.  When entering this command, the shell (cmd.exe) does not expand foo*. Instead, the string foo* is passed to the del command (which I realize is builtin). There is no filename expansion to a long list of names. Instead, del does a search for names matching foo* and deletes each matching file one at a time. On the Mac, that is what find . -name "foo*" -maxdepth 1 -exec rm {} \; does. If you are going to continue to use a Mac, then you are going to have to learn how to properly use a shell and the commands.

Thanks for the collaboration here. I’ve edited this into a previous comment: “Architecturally, historically yours is the wrong approach and designed to fail.” And I agree with the sentiment. With kindness @Sarien your approach is flawed and compromised by design. Hire a tool to do your work like find and xargs - there is no shell suitable to bend to your will unless you write one.

Yes, I understand that I am asking the shell to expand the filenames and pass them to the program. I don't see how that means this approach is historically wrong except for the size constraint having a historic value.

I feel your approach here is wrong. Use find and xargs as core programs designed to avoid overloading the call chain of the shell. Builtins are designed to handle long text without buffer overflow. For reasons exec can be abused for buffer overflow and has a fixed limit by design.
This is how dozens of engineers have designed shells and Unix for decades. You don’t have to like it, agree with it, but you are constrained by these implementation and security design choices in how the shell works.

The design choice was to have a limit and I am only asking to increase that limit. Note, the limit is not a compile time constant. I don't think I understand what the issue with exec and buffer overflows is that you're mentioning.

You should be able to dig deeper here as both the shell and xnu are open source @Sarien https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/xnu
